# svn creating branch of branch

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn

We have a branch we are working from and I now want to create a branch from this branch to add some new features to the branch.  How cam I do this is such a way that I can easily sync down the changes made to the parent branch and merge my changes into the parent branch?

We are using TortiseSVN.

Thanks!

Comment: have you read the red bean book?

Comment: Hi.  I read the red bean book and could not determine if branching would cover the scenario we need.  Multiple people would be working in the branch of a branch.  When anyone commits changes they need go only into the branch of branch NOT into the branch.  However, they need to get changes from the branch into the branch of branch.  Is this possible?  If so, how do I set up the folders?  Do I create a branch folder under the first branch?

Comment: I would try the way I have described in my answer. And do exactly as the branching example in the book except for you 'trunk' is 'branch1' and 'branch' is 'branch2'. Every once in a while of course you get changes from the 'trunk' into 'branch1'. as branch2 is copy of branch1 you should still be able to get this changes that bubbled from trunk to brnach1 into branch2 by merging brnach1 into branch2, there is no added complexity: branch1 is copy of trunk and branch2 is copy of branch1 so you should think about them simple that way. I would also recommend that you first do this through cmd-line

Answer (score 1):

```
YourProject/
           /trunk - main line of development
           /branch1 - made by the 'copy' command on trunk
           /branch2 - made by the 'copy' command on 'branch1'
```

You can safely think of `branch2` as you would think of `branch1` and merge directly from branch2 to trunk as it is a branch (or more accurately a copy) of `trunk`.

I recommend you to read in [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) (I think the PDF edition is the best) up to and including the chapter of 'basic branching and merging'.

Answer (score 0):

As branching is merely a copy operation, branching from a branch is equal to branching from trunk or any other directory you may want to branch. I would recommend the SVN book for a more in depth explanation of branching: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.using.html.